# php setcookie записывает не туда

Tags: php

Запись в куки производится из файла http://yourdomain.ru/login/login.php

```
setcookie("uid", $id, time()+3600);
```

Но если перейти в http://yourdomain.ru/index.php то в куки ничего нет. Зато если перейти в папку login и просмотреть куки там, то значение записано. Как сделать, чтобы из папки записывалось в главную директорию сайта?

Comment: setcookie("uid", $id, time()+3600, '/');  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Фейспалм... Спасибо